# Can I get the number of Instagram pictures for an instagram area?

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I would like to use the python-instagram API in order to find the number of pictures for an area of my city. The aim is to create a heat-map using the number of pictures count.

I have been downloading pictures from certain locations manually but it would be nice to get the picture count for an area.

I was able to create something like this using manually downloaded data:

[image]

Is there a possibility to get the counts automatically?

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picodash - location search to search any city and set a radius and get all the latest posts, you can view heat map or cluster map any time. You can also load posts from any date range and view heatmap.

You can use this Insatgram API to search posts by location:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

[image]

Comment: in sandobox you will get only your and your sandbox users posts, and they are not approving this permission in API, so you cannot get fully functionality of this API anymore. Only apps that was already been approved will work.

Comment: Thank you. is there any chance to re introduce these API in Instagram Graph API ?

Comment: Instagram has not announced ant future support for this API in Graph API